# How to raise exception from a plugin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, doorkeeper

When I raise an exception from within [doorkeeper], the exception gets handled within doorkeeper(which is obvious).

**File path** `vendor/gems/doorkeeper-2.2.0/lib/doorkeeper/errors.rb`

I handle my other exceptions inside **base_controller**.  Is it possible to process the exceptions in **base_controller** instead of within the plugin/gem doorkeeper?

Answer (score 1):

Exceptions "bubble up" through the call stack from the point where they're raised, until they're caught (usually by a `rescue` block). Once an exception is caught, it stops bubbling up and there's no detecting it higher up in the call stack. So if the gem handles this exception internally, there's no way for you to hear about it higher up the stack (eg. in BaseController where the gem is called).

However, typically I wouldn't expect a gem to rescue *every* exception; I'd expect it to only rescue types of exceptions that it expects and knows full-well how to handle internally. When it rescues an exception, essentially the gem is saying "I know what this exception is, where it came from, why it occurred, and what should be done with it. I'm 100% confident that I can take care of all implications of this exception and no one else needs to even know about it." If this guarantee can't be made, then the exception shouldn't have been rescued in the first place.

Perhaps instead of the exception, the gem passes you some sort of error code or status flag to indicate that something went wrong? If so you can use that in BaseController. Otherwise, I think you should just trust the gem to do its job (or if you *don't* trust it, find an alternative).

Answer (score 1):

Ruby has the capability for monkey patching classes, even if they are in modules, but I have never seen it applied to errors. Errors don't have attributes or methods, so nothing to extend. Since the Doorkeeper error file looks like this

```
module Doorkeeper
  module Errors
    class DoorkeeperError < StandardError
    end

    class InvalidAuthorizationStrategy < DoorkeeperError
    end

    class InvalidTokenStrategy < DoorkeeperError
    end

    class MissingRequestStrategy < DoorkeeperError
    end
  end
end
```

You can always rescue and rehandle the error, shouldn't be a problem if you want to do something custom.

```
def raise_and_rescue  
  begin  
    puts 'I am before the raise.'  
    raise Doorkeeper::Errors::InvalidAuthorizationStrategy  
    puts 'I am after the raise.'  
  rescue  
    puts 'I am rescued.'  
  end  
end  

p raise_and_rescue
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Similar to your suggestion, I had already added a custom exception inside Doorkeeper errors.rb file and able to successfully rescue it, the only prob is the Doorkeeper exception message formatting is quiet different and for all remaining exceptions that are handled inside my base controller I have format like `{error, message, error code and a custom error code`, so it's difficult for me to inject custom error code inside the GEM. I want a common code.

Comment: Once you rescue, you could possibly wrap the error in your base class and rethrow with the format you want.